# Memory Leak warning I can't solve

Tags: objective-c, iphone, cocoa, memory-management, memory-leaks

The static analyzer is showing up a leak in this block of code (specifically the link with the copy in it):

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI 
 qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
{
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"item"]) 
    {
        [elements setObject:title forKey:@"title"];
        [elements setObject:date forKey:@"date"];
        [elements setObject:summary forKey:@"summary"];
        [elements setObject:link forKey:@"link"];

        [posts addObject:[elements copy]];
    }
}
```

I tried releasing the copied object but I still get the warning. Am I missing something?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**You created new copy which you don't release.**

This returns new `elements` object with ref count 1 which you are responsible to deallocate since you've just created a copy:

```
[elements copy];
```

In this line you add the new created copy to `posts` which looks like collection.
All collections retain new values, so you pass your new copy with ref count 1 and posts increase the ref count to 2 by retaining it.

```
[posts addObject:[elements copy]];
```

On release `posts` will send to each element `release` which will decrement ref count to 1 so `elements` does not get deallocated and you end up with memory leak.

Remove the `copy` and see if that helps:

```
[post addObject:elements];
```

Answer (score 3):

Just to make one point perfectly clear:

> I tried releasing the copied object but I still get the warning.

You mean you tried this?

```
    [posts addObject:[elements copy]];
    [elements release];
```

That doesn't solve the problem, and it may cause a second problem.

The problem you started with is that you are leaking *the copy*—the object that the `copy` method returned, the object that you added to `posts`. That problem remains: You have not released the copy.

The problem you've added is that you are releasing the *original* object, which may not be what you intend; I can't say for sure without seeing your other code. You need to make sure not to release `elements` until you no longer need it.

You may want to send `elements` a `removeAllObjects` message instead; this will keep the object around, but empty it out in preparation for the next element.

On an unrelated note, you may also want to rename `elements` to more accurately reflect its dictionary nature and to abstract it away from its XML representation. “`elements`” sounds like an array to me. “`feedItemProperties`” might be more appropriate.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I see what I was doing wrong now. Thanks.